# Is there a way to provide hints to the solver, about which paths are better?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

Is there a way to prefer certain paths over others during solving? This is really a performance question. When I put all my logic together, it generates 1000’s of solution and this takes exponentially increasing time.  These really are all valid solutions, so I could do something like `(run 1 …)` instead of `(run* …)` but this gives me an arbitrary solution.  What I want to do is be able to provide some hints about which paths are better.

I know, I could get the one best answer by sorting them with a custom comparator, but this doesn’t help the performance problem.

Here’s a simplified, contrived example:

```
(require
  '[clojure.core.logic :refer :all]
  '[clojure.core.logic.fd :as fd]))

(defn multipleo
  [multiple value domain]
  (fresh [n]
    (fd/in multiple domain)
    (fd/in n (fd/interval 1 10))
    (fd/* n multiple value)))

(run* [q]
  (multipleo q 60 (fd/domain 30 24 15 12)))
=> (12 15 30)
```

12, 15 and 30 are all valid solutions, but the one I want is the largest `(-> *1 sort last)`, but again I want to do it with the solver so `(run 1 [q] (multipleo q 60 (fd/domain 30 24 15 12)))` would ideally produce `(30)`.

Comment: I don't know about fd, but for ordinary logic variables you can simply put the "preferred" path before the others in your `conde` or whatever, and that gets searched first.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @amlloy's suggestion, I can try this:

```
(defn multipleo
  [multiple value]
  (fresh [n]
    (conde
      [(== multiple 6)]
      [(== multiple 3)])
    (fd/in n (fd/interval 1 10))
    (fd/* n multiple value)))

(run* [q] (multipleo q 12))
=> (6 3)
```

This seems to work.  As far as I can tell, ordering the domain in fd/in has no impact.  But if I move the domain entries intp a `conde` in the order that I prefer, that works.  Without the `conde` the above code would produce `(3 6)` instead.  However, this is *much slower* than the fd/in approach.  I guess fd/in does some nice performance tricks as compared to just conde.

I also tried `condu`, but this doesn't work as I would expect.

```
(defn multipleo
  [multiple value]
  (fresh [n]
    (condu
      [(== multiple 6)]
      [(== multiple 3)])
    (fd/in n (fd/interval 1 10))
    (fd/* n multiple value)))

(run* [q] (multipleo q 3))
=> ()
```

I would have expected the first `condu` group to fail, since the overall logic can not succeed w/ multiple=6, in this example.  Can anyone help me understand why that doesn't work as I expect?